# Syntax for onchange event to update a hidden text box with the index value of a select box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, hidden

I mean, I feel like a total idiot, but I just can't seem to get this right, even after searching for almost two hours.

This select is followed by a hidden text field:

```
<select name="location_id" class="select green-gradient" single>
  <option value="2">New York</option>
  <option value="3">London</option>
  <option value="4">Singapore</option>
  <option value="5">San Francisco</option>
  <option value="6">Milan</option>
</select>
<input type='text'  name="selected_location_id" class="hidden" value="">
```

// I usually use this code for checkboxes. It toggles the contents of a hidden text box. I understand that checking a select's values is different. But I can't seem to get it right.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.switch').change(function( ){
        if($(this).next().val() == 1){
            $(this).next().val(0);
        } else {
            $(this).next().val(1);
        }
    });
})
```

// I've tried this: but it's not useful since I need to do this for all selects on the page. And it still doesnt update the hidden text box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.select').change(function( ){
     var selectedValue = $(this "option:selected").val();
     $(this).next().val(selectedValue);
   });
})
```

// Maybe I'm just tired. But it's time to ask for help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be

```
$('select').change ///(without the dot)
```

not

```
$('.switch').change
```

neither

```
$('.select').change
```

Comment: Thank you. so the .syntax addresses the style, and without the dot, the type of input.  Thanks.

Comment: yes. that's right. So, if this solved your problem, you may accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedValue = $("option:selected").val();
```

Works in a jsfiddle by taking the "this" out.

Comment: If there are 6 select elements in the page, each with a selected option, what value will you get?

Answer (score 1):

Within the listener, `this` references the element. You can also get the name of the hidden element from the select element's name, so if they're in a form:

```
this.form['selected_' + this.name].value = this.value;
```

and you're done without a single function call.

Comment: Impressive.  Thank you very much. 
So, this.form['my_text_box_name'].value=this.value;
Perfect.